# Why doesn't the scrollPane become scrollable when I add elements to it?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, scrollpane

I am making a GUI in java using swing and I am having some trouble with the scrollPane. As a bit of context, I have a JPanel called **leftPanel**, on which everything that I am about to show you sits on. This is how it is created:

```
leftPanel = new JPanel();
leftPanel.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
leftPanel.setBackground(new Color(51, 51, 51));
leftPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
```

On this panel I then have the following JPanels (they all have something inside, but it's not relevant to the problem):

```
JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
topPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 35));
topPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
topPanel.setBackground(new Color(51, 51, 51));
```

```
JPanel fenPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
fenPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 60));
fenPanel.setBackground(new Color(255, 18, 18));
```

```
JPanel perftPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
perftPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 35));
perftPanel.setBackground(new Color(55, 147, 86));
```

Lastly, I have **resultsPanel** and **scrollPane**, which are the reason for this post

```
resultsPanel = new JPanel();
resultsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(resultsPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
resultsPanel.setBackground(new Color(51, 51, 51));

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(resultsPanel);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

leftPanel.add(topPanel);
leftPanel.add(fenPanel);
leftPanel.add(perftPanel);
leftPanel.add(scrollPane);
```

**resultsPanel** is initially empty, but whenever a button is pressed, some stuff gets printed on there. This is how I do that:

```
//This thing is in a loop, so more than 1 JLabel is added

JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 20));
panel.setBackground(new Color(51, 51, 51));

JLabel label = null;
if (count == fishCount) {
    label = new JLabel(counterSplit[counterIndex]);
    label.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.BOLD, 12));
    label.setBackground(new Color(51, 51, 51));
    label.setForeground(new Color(66, 131, 0));
    label.setOpaque(true);
} else {
    label = new JLabel(counterSplit[counterIndex] + "Stockfish: " + fishCount);
    label.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.BOLD, 12));
    label.setBackground(new Color(51, 51, 51));
    label.setForeground(new Color(126, 0, 0));
    label.setOpaque(true);
}

panel.add(label);
resultsPanel.add(panel);
```

With the code above I didn't specify a preferred size, and for some reason **resultsPanel** isn't expanding to fit all the content.

If I do add a preferred size, the JLables get printed fine, but the **resultsPanel** only shows a couple of lines and I can't scroll to see the rest of them, even though they are 100% getting added. I know they are getting printed, because If I make **resultsPanel** really big I can see the labels there. For some reason though it never becomes scrollable and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I also wrote this bit of code just to make sure I am not going crazy

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("ScrollPane Example");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
contentPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(contentPanel);
frame.add(scrollPane);

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    contentPanel.add(new JLabel("Label " + i));
}

frame.setSize(300, 200);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

This works exactly as expected and is what I am trying to achieve. If anyone can point out what I am doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `setPreferredSize` probably isn't helping your cause

Comment: Did you try making an example with a JFrame, ScrollPanel, ResultsPanel (a panel with a box layout), Then iteratively add your nested components? It seems like you could have a complete compilable example from that.

Comment: BoxLayout and FlowLayout aren’t good choices for a container with a JScrollPane in it.  JScrollPanes aren’t very effective unless placed in a layout that will make their size change when the container’s size changes.  There are other layouts, and some of them are very useful, particularly BorderLayout and GridBagLayout.  Notice that your last bit of code is placing the JScrollPane in the center of a BorderLayout (because [that’s the default for a JFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFrame.html)).

Comment: @VGR A GirdBagLayout actually gave me the exact results I wanted, thanks! I now only have this weird bug where if resultsPanel has some text in it and I interact with the GUI, everything messes up, but I'll see how I fix that